# Group a map into another mapped based on a property within the map

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following code:

```
class Scratch {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Id> idDefinitions = Map.of(
      "A", new Id(Group.GROUP_A),
      "B", new Id(Group.GROUP_B),
      "C", new Id(Group.GROUP_A));

    Map<String, Object> ids = Map.of("A", new Object(), "B", new Object(), "C", new Object());
    
    Map<Group, Map<String, Object>> idsByGroup = ?
  }

  private static class Id {
    private Group group;
    public Id(Group group) {
      this.group = group;
    }
  }

  private enum Group {
    GROUP_A,
    GROUP_B
  }
}
```

Based on the idDefinitions and the ids, I want to create a new Map where all the ids are grouped by their Group. I can solve that iteratively with a for-loop but I'm wondering if there are stream alternatives, using the groupingBy collector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just use `Collectors.groupingBy` to group by `Group`. This will give you a `Map<Group, List<Map.Entry<String, Id>>>`

But we want the values of the map to be another `Map`, so we should pass a [downstream collector](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) to `groupingBy`, the `toMap` collector. The downstream is a stream of `Map.Entry<String, Id>`, so the maps' keys would be `entry.getKey`, and the values would be the `Object`s from `ids`.

```
Map<Group, Map<String, Object>> idsByGroup = idDefinitions
    .entrySet().stream()
    .filter(x -> ids.containsKey(x.getKey()))
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            x -> x.getValue().group,
            Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                x -> ids.get(x.getKey())
            )
        )
    );
```

Comment: Thanks. This works pretty well if all idDefinitions appear in the ids as well. But if I have more definitions than ids, that doesn't work.

Comment: @SCM I see. I think you can just `filter` the ids that are not in `ids` out. Edited.